# How I can check my current position on a FTP server

Tags: directory, ftp

Using `cd` I can change my folder on a FTP server ([Link](https://www.msnoob.com/ftp-commands-for-windows.html#:%7E:text=cd-,Changes%20directory.,-close)).

How can I determine which directory I am currently in?

I use the Windows 10 standard `ftp`. I starting the tool `cmd.exe` and than I type `ftp` / `open`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`pwd` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-pwd_1):

```
ftp> pwd
257 "/" is current directory.
```